# How to animate display of same View Controller but with updated content

Tags: swift4, ios11, xcode9, uiviewanimation

I want to animate an update to a sceen's content as if transitioning to a different View Controller.  For example, imagine a scene of a calendar page with today's events.  A swipe to the left updates the content to tomorrow's events but the View Controller and scene are the same.  Still, I'd like to animate the new content sliding in from the right.

I've tried animating moving the entire view to the left.  And that works, but it reveals a black screen beneath, which although quickly replaced with the correct content is nevertheless jarring.

I remember back in the HyperCard days you could lock the display of a card, update the contents, then unlock the display with a transition, say, a dissolve or wipe.  I understand that is probably not how iOS does things, but I mention it just to help describe what I'm trying to do.

Adding code that does gesture recognition and move...

```
@objc func swipeDetected(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let calendar = Calendar.current

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case .left:
            // move current page to the left
            animateViewMoving(right: false, timeInterval: 0.3)
            // update content
            currentDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
            populateSchedItems()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            // return page with no duration
            animateViewMoving(right: true, timeInterval: 0.0)

        case .right:
            // move page to left with no duration
            animateViewMoving(right: false, timeInterval: 0.0)
            // update content
            currentDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: currentDate)!
            populateSchedItems()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            // slide new content in from the left
            animateViewMoving(right: true, timeInterval: 0.3)

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

func animateViewMoving (toTheRight: Bool, timeInterval: Double) {
    let frameWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let movementDuration:TimeInterval = timeInterval
    let movement:CGFloat = ( toTheRight ? frameWidth : -frameWidth)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: movement, dy: 0)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Comment: "I've tried animating moving the entire view to the left" Could you show us that code, please?

Comment: The moving is in response to a "Swipe Left" gesture.  Here is the gesture handling code and the function that does the move

Comment: "I remember back in the HyperCard days you could lock the display of a card, update the contents, then unlock the display with a transition, say, a dissolve or wipe" There is something very comparable in iOS: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_transitions But it is unlikely that any of the built-in transitions corresponds exactly to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a *snapshot view* of the current contents and place it behind the current view. (This will give us something other than the black window to look at behind the animation.) Now do exactly what you're already doing: move the real view off to the side and animate it in. Now quietly remove the snapshot view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that a try.

Comment: That worked like a champ and suggested some variations of your idea.  For example, by grabbing a screen image and creating programmatically a UIImage in front of the the other scene subviews, I could then update those subview contents and slide the UImage to reveal them.This led to a small library of single-ViewController content-update transitions.  Thanks again!